# How add InfluxDB on Superset

Tags: python, influxdb, apache-superset

I would like add influxdb on superset, I installed influxalchemy, after I tried url sqlaclchemy 'infludb://...' but doesn't work. And there's no explication to how to do.

My error on superset:

> ERROR: {"error: "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was: \nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:influxdb"}

Would you be able to do?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to be using SQLAlchemy? The README on InfluxAlchemy states: "Query InfluxDB using **SQLAlchemy-style** syntax", not "using SQLAlchemy".

Comment: So, how using SQLAlchemy-style on superset and read influxdb plugin ?

Comment: Read their [README](https://github.com/amancevice/influxalchemy) carefully. It contains instructions on how to use InfluxAlchemy to connect and perform queries. You don't need SQLAlchemy in this case. On the other hand Apache Superset seems to use SQLA, so this might not help you with that. I suppose you've read https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/5588, which seems incorrect.